# Transform list in a dataframe (same row, different columns) in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I got one list from a dataframe's column:

```
list_recs = [row[0] for row in df_recs.select("name").collect()]
```

The list looks like this:

```
Out[243]: ['COL-4560', 'D65-2242', 'D18-4751', 'D68-3303']
```

I want to transform it in a new dataframe, which value in one different column. I tried doing this:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
rdd = sc.parallelize(list_recs)
recs = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(SKU=str(x[0]), REC_01=str(x[1]), REC_02=str(x[2]), REC_03=str(x[3])))#, REC_04=str(x[4]), REC_0=str(x[5])))
schemaRecs = sqlContext.createDataFrame(recs)
```

But the outcome I'm getting is:

```
+---+------+------+------+
|SKU|REC_01|REC_02|REC_03|
+---+------+------+------+
|  C|     O|     L|     -|
|  D|     6|     5|     -|
|  D|     1|     8|     -|
|  D|     6|     8|     -|
+---+------+------+------+
```

What I wanted:

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|SKU       |REC_01       |REC_02       |REC_03       |
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|  COL-4560|     D65-2242|     D18-4751|     D68-3303|
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I've also tried `spark.createDataFrame(lista_recs, StringType())` but got all the items in the same column.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define **schema** and use `spark.createDataFrame()`

```
list_recs=['COL-4560', 'D65-2242', 'D18-4751', 'D68-3303']

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([StructField("SKU", StringType(), True), StructField("REC_01", StringType(), True), StructField("REC_02", StringType(), True), StructField("REC_03", StringType(), True)])

spark.createDataFrame([list_recs],schema).show()
#+--------+--------+--------+--------+
#|     SKU|  REC_01|  REC_02|  REC_03|
#+--------+--------+--------+--------+
#|COL-4560|D65-2242|D18-4751|D68-3303|
#+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: It worked very well, thank you! My problem now is that my end goal was to iterate over many lists and add them to the dataframe, but they have different number of columns.

Comment: Sure, Please open as new question (with some sample data), So that all community members can able to **view and help** to get it resolve.